# Spark Connection Refused

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

We use GraphX library of Spark to calculate PageRank for our graph which contains 50M vertices and 100M edges, and when we use YARN for scheduling the job, the job fails in the middle of the same stage, and it runs like charm when use use standalone scheduler. The config is following:

We have 4 machines, running Spark 1.2.1 on Cloudera's Hadoop 2.4
each has 12 cores and 64 Gb of RAM, 1Gb eth.
we launch the app with following config:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --class com.test.analytics.spark.graphx.TestPageRank  --master yarn-cluster  --num-executors 4  --executor-memory 20g  --executor-cores 12  --queue root.pagerank /tmp/mvn-spark_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here's the stacktrace

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to cluster3/192.168.10.3:43492
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$.org$apache$spark$shuffle$hash$BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$$unpackBlock$1(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$$anonfun$3.apply(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:83)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.BlockStoreShuffleFetcher$$anonfun$3.apply(BlockStoreShuffleFetcher.scala:83)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.EdgePartition.updateVertices(EdgePartition.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.ReplicatedVertexView$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ReplicatedVertexView.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.ReplicatedVertexView$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ReplicatedVertexView.scala:73)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.EdgeRDDImpl$$anonfun$mapEdgePartitions$1.apply(EdgeRDDImpl.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.EdgeRDDImpl$$anonfun$mapEdgePartitions$1.apply(EdgeRDDImpl.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:618)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:618)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeRDD.compute(EdgeRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
...
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to cluster3/192.168.10.3:43492
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:191)
at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:156)
at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:140)
at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.access$200(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher$1.run(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:170)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: cluster3/192.168.10.3:43492
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:208)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:287)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
...
```

Comment: What do you see in the logs of the executor? (`cluster3`)

Comment: Sorry dude, it was long ago don't have logs anymore, the issue resolved itself after we've doubled our nodes.